# Postman is not showing the raw RestApi responses when i use Project lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I use general java boilerplate to create entity, it returns all value correctly. But, in case of Project Lombok it is is not returning responses. I am sharing the code. please guide me to solve the issue.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name="Designation")
public class Designation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int Id;
    
    private String Designation;
    
    private float Salary;
}
```

And the Constructor looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/desig")
public class DesignationController {

    private DesignationService designationService;

    @Autowired
    public DesignationController(DesignationService designationService) {
        this.designationService = designationService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/designation")
    public List<Designation> getAllDesignation(){
        return designationService.findAllDesignation();
    }
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class DesignationServiceImpl implements DesignationService {

    private DesignationRepository designationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DesignationServiceImpl(DesignationRepository designationRepository) {
        this.designationRepository = designationRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Designation> findAllDesignation() {
        return designationRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface DesignationRepository extends JpaRepository<Designation, Integer>{
    
}
```

PostMan Response:

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

Response using debugger on eclipse Console,

```
2020-06-30 18:45:30.227 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [1]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.227 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([designat2_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [A]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.227 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([salary3_0_] : [FLOAT]) - [50000.0]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.227 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.227 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([designat2_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [B]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.227 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([salary3_0_] : [FLOAT]) - [45000.0]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.227 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [3]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.228 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([designat2_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [C]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.228 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([salary3_0_] : [FLOAT]) - [40000.0]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.228 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [4]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.228 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([designat2_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [D]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.228 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([salary3_0_] : [FLOAT]) - [35000.0]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.228 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [5]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.228 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([designat2_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [DFD]
2020-06-30 18:45:30.228 TRACE 11772 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([salary3_0_] : [FLOAT]) - [35000.0]
```

Can anyone here please tell me why response is not coming in postman, where as i can fetch data on eclipse console..

Comment: The `@Getter @Setter` annotations don't do anything; @Data already implies them. Consider updating your question to show the raw REST API's response.

Comment: Removing getter setter didn't make it work. is there any other mistake i'm making. @rzwitserloot

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting that would fix anything - I was merely saying those don't do anything. Hard to say without seeing the REST API's response.

Comment: Can you take a look of your generated .class file and just check if the getter is here.

Answer (score 0):

Print your designation list in Controll to see whether the value is well set.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/desig")
@Slf4j
public class DesignationController {

    private DesignationService designationService;

    @Autowired
    public DesignationController(DesignationService designationService) {
        this.designationService = designationService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/designation")
    public List<Designation> getAllDesignation(){
        List<Designation> designationList = designationService.findAllDesignation();
        log.info("designationList = {}", designationList);
    }
}
```